# VisualStudio 2015 on Embedded Win 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-7, embedded

I need to port a VS2005 project to VS2015 project. The development needs to be done on a PC running with Embedded Win 7 OS. So my question if whether VS 2015 can be installed on a PC running embedded Win7 OS?

Comment: @Olaf This question specifically relates to Embedded Win 7. Which is an Embedded OS. I've put the [embedded] tag back. If you feel that's a mistake, perhaps we could find a tag that better fits the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Editions of Visual Studio 2015 (Except Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows 10) will run on Windows 7 with Service Pack 1: https://www.visualstudio.com/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs

Unfortunately, while you can develop for all versions of Windows Embedded 7 you will not be able to use: "Tools for Native and Managed Classic Windows Desktop Development" https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/visual-studio-15-compatibility-vs#developWindows